# Django form error customizing

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to add custom data to django form errors.

For instance, if user input exceeds available stock quantity, I'd like to add the available stock quantity to the error data.

Upon inspecting form.errors, one can look at the error code,(InsufficientStock) then it can look for the `remaining quantity` in the error data.

especially when we are working in ajax.

*Edit*

I'm trying to set the quantity to the available max in the client side using javascript.

Comment: How do you raise the errors? you should show your (relevant) validation code

Answer (score 0):

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self):
        self.available_quantity = AVAILABLE_QUANTITY

    def clean_quantity(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['quantity']>self.available_quantity:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry, you only have %d stocks left' % self.available_quantity)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've clarified what I want in the question.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to do like this. Could you show some code how you plan to achieve this?